# What happens to imports when a new process is spawned?

Tags: python, module, multiprocessing, py4j

What happens to imported modules variables when a new process is spawned?

IE

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=settings.MAX_PROCESSES) as executor:
    for stuff in executor.map(foo, paths):
```

where:

```
  def foo(str):
  x = someOtherModule.fooBar()
```

where foobar is accessing things declared at the start of someOtherModule:

someOtherModule.py:

```
 myHat='green'
 def fooBar():
   return myHat
```

Specifically, I have a module (called Y) that has a py4j gateway initialized at the top, outside of any function. In module X I'm loading several files at once, and the function that sorts through the data after loading uses a function in Y which in turn uses the gateway.

Is this design pythonic?
Should I be importing my Y module after each new process is spawned? OR is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Py4J author here. If you are accessing the same gateway from different processes, don't do that because you will be sharing a socket with multiple processes Py4J is not designed to handle this scenario (it is thread-safe though)! Instead, create a new gateway instance per process.

Comment: What if I wanted multiple instances of my java program? Could that be accomplished? (As in a new gateway for a new instance of the java for each new multiprocessing.process)

Comment: That will work, but each Java process must use a different port (configurable when you create a GatewayServer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, `fork` will be used to spawn the child, so anything in the global scope of the parent will also be available in the child, with copy-on-write semantics.

On Windows, anything you `import` at the module-level in the `__main__` module of the parent process will get re-imported in the child.

This means that if you have a parent module (let's call it `someModule`) like this:

```
import someOtherModule
import concurrent.futures

def foo(str):
    x = someOtherModule.fooBar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=settings.MAX_PROCESSES) as executor:
        for stuff in executor.map(foo, paths):
            # stuff
```

And `someOtherModule` looks like this:

```
myHat='green'
def fooBar():
    return myHat
```

In this example, `someModule` is the `__main__` module of the script. So, on Linux, the `myHat` instance you get in the child will be a copy-on-write version of the one in `someModule`. On Windows, each child process will re-import `someModule` as soon as they load, which will result in `someOtherModule` being re-imported as well.

I don't know enough about py4j `Gateway` objects to tell if you for sure if this is the behavior you want or not. If the `Gateway` object is pickleable, you could explicitly pass it to each child instead, but you'd have to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
import someOtherModule
import multiprocessing

def foo(str):
    x = someOtherModule.fooBar()

def init(hat):
    someOtherModule.myHat = hat

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hat = someOtherModule.myHat
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(settings.MAX_PROCESSES,
                                initializer=init, initargs=(hat,))
    for stuff in pool.map(foo, paths):
            # stuff
```

It doesn't seem like you have a need to do this for you use-case, though. You're probably fine using the re-import.

Comment: Had no idea how Windows worked with the multi-processing module. Really interesting

Comment: I know this post date long ago, but I got a question about windows. When you say it "re-import" the module, you mean it re-import as sys.modules or as a new import ? Will they share the same variable or will windows import it as independent module ? Thank you !

Comment: @ Léo It's a brand new import. Windows re-executes the `__main__` module in the child process.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new process, a `fork()` is called, which clones the entire process and stack, memory space etc. This is why multi-processing is considered more expensive than multi-threading since the copying is expensive.

So to answer your question, all "imported module variables" are cloned. You can modify them as you wish, but your original parent process won't see this change.

**EDIT:** 
This for Unix based systems only. See Dano's answer for Unix+Windows answer.

Comment: I thought windows used spawn because it didnt have fork....for global variables inside X I have to pass them to the child processes because they are empty.

Comment: @user2757902 That's correct. There is no `fork` on Windows. On Windows, the child process will re-import that parent's `__main__` module, and any module that needs to be imported to unpickle any arguments you explicitly passed to the child, but that's it.